# How to set value of input without locking user input

Tags: javascript

I have multiple inputs and i want to display result in input and change it freely.
When i type 5 in first input it should display 5 in the second. But how to change the value of second input and display it in the first? I want to be able to constantly change the values.

```js
function calc(){
var val1 = document.getElementById("val1");
let val2 = document.getElementById("value2");

val2.value = 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="value1" type="number" value="" oninput="calc()">
<input id="value2" type="number" value="" oninput="calc()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? Making some relation between the inputs but keeping both changeable?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an additional parameter to your function and change the values as per the parameters.

```js
function calc(num){
var val1 = document.getElementById("value1");
let val2 = document.getElementById("value2");

num ? val1.value = val2.value : val2.value = val1.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="number" value="" oninput="calc(0)">
<input id="value2" type="number" value="" oninput="calc(1)">
```

I have replaced the `if else` condition with a ternary operator. I hope that you are familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="value1" type="number" value="" oninput="document.getElementById('value2').value =this.value">
<input id="value2" type="number" value="" oninput="document.getElementById('value1').value =this.value">
</body>
</html>
```

Use like this